# Push heroku freez at "BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock"

Tags: heroku

when I push on heroku, it stops at

> `

BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock

`

and its freez at this time?

Do you have the solution?

thank you so much

Comment: Might be something on heroku's side. I'd suggest try to open up a support ticket on heroku. Though status.heroku.com show no issues. But i did face the same issue with one of the apps hosted on heroku. The same code deployment worked around an hour or so back but either it timeouts or stuck in progress. Checked with a couple of test apps on heroku.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We can't tell you anything useful with so little information.

Comment: Were experiencing the same issue. We haven't found a way to resolve it also.

Comment: I'm having same issue. Probably heroku problem.

Comment: Heroku has just updated it a minute ago on their status as well https://status.heroku.com/ and listed this issue there

Answer (score 0):

We are having the exact same error.

Heroku just updated their status page: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2383
It seems to be an issue on their end.